# How to fix error - failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build.gradle, apk

I am creating a flutter app and when I run my code, I get this error message:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\aayus\OneDrive\Desktop\MYP 5\IB Unit ICT\flutter app buddy\flutter_application_buddy> & 'c:\Users\aayus\OneDrive\Desktop\MYP 5\IB Unit ICT\flutter app buddy\flutter_application_buddy\lib\main.dart'
PS C:\Users\aayus\OneDrive\Desktop\MYP 5\IB Unit ICT\flutter app buddy\flutter_application_buddy> flutter run
Launching lib\main.dart on AC2001 in debug mode...
Parameter format not correct -

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     AAPT: error: failed to open APK: Invalid file.



* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 14s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                                  
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        15.3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
PS C:\Users\aayus\OneDrive\Desktop\MYP 5\IB Unit ICT\flutter app buddy\flutter_application_buddy>
```

Can someone please guide me with this and help me fix this error?

Comment: What are you calling before `flutter run`? Are your IDE don't showing errors in code?

Comment: @fartem, I am using VSCode and the IDE is showing the error

Comment: Can you add an error from IDE to the question?

Comment: I have already added the error, what else do you want? Let me know and I'll add it

Comment: Error not from console, have you get an error in Visual Editor?

Comment: I just got this error @fartem

Comment: Try to clean project (`flutter clean`) and run again.

Comment: Tried that as well, did not work and I can see the same error again

Comment: Can you move to `android` directory in your project and run `gradlew clean build --stacktrace`?

Answer (score 1):

Did you manually migrate your Flutter project to [AndroidX](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/androidx-migration)? If yes, I suggest checking the `compileSdkVersion` and make sure that it's at least set to 28. This issue seems to be similar to this [GitHub issue thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/44760).